# Align lower lines of a set of equations at an extra point

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I have a series of equations which I want to align at the equals sign. However I also wish for the left side of the last three lines to be left-aligned with each other (i.e. aligned to the widest of the three, not aligned flush to the left edge of the page).

Here's what I have currently:

[image: Image of current output.]

Here's what I'd like:

[image: Image of desired output.]

My code is as follows:

```
\begin{align*}
\text{Solve } D_1 = D_2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2} &= \sqrt{(y-2)^2}\\
(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 &= \quad (y-2)^2\\
(x^2 - 6x + 9) + (y^2 - 8y + 16) &= \quad y^2 - 4y + 4\\
x^2 - 6x + 21 &= \quad 4y\\
x^2 - 6x - 4y + 21 &= \quad 0
\end{align*}
```

It seems that what I'd like is an extra alignment point for the last 3 rows, but I haven't been able to find anything like that.

I've seen the *aligned* environment, but I believe that would break the alignment of the equals signs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `array` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
\begin{array}{rll}
\text{Solve } D_1 
    & = D_2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2}    & = \sqrt{(y-2)^2}      \\
    &\hfill (x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2                       & = \quad (y-2)^2       \\
    & (x^2 - 6x + 9) + (y^2 - 8y + 16)              & = \quad y^2 - 4y + 4  \\
    & x^2 - 6x + 21                                 & = \quad 4y\\
    & x^2 - 6x - 4y + 21                            & = \quad 0
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The alignment seems very confusing but ...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newlength\zzz
\settowidth\zzz{$\displaystyle x^2 - 6x + 9) + (y^2 - 8y + 16)$}

\begin{align*}
\text{Solve } D_1 = D_2 \Rightarrow \sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2} &= \sqrt{(y-2)^2}\\
(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 &= \quad (y-2)^2\\
(x^2 - 6x + 9) + (y^2 - 8y + 16) &= \quad y^2 - 4y + 4\\
\makebox[\zzz][l]{$\displaystyle x^2 - 6x + 21$} &= \quad 4y\\
\makebox[\zzz][l]{$\displaystyle x^2 - 6x - 4y + 21$} &= \quad 0
\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like the most flexible solution, layout wise. Unfortunately the necessary commands aren't supported in my case (a third party website with MathJax).

Comment: @NeilHaskins ah well mathjax doesn't use tex so things are different in that case.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a slightly different way of computing, and another layout, with the `\ArrowBetweenLines`command from `mathtools`, which requires using `alignat{2}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\intertext{Solve $ D_1 = D_2 \Rightarrow $}
& & \sqrt{(x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2} &= \sqrt{(y-2)^2}\\
 \ArrowBetweenLines
& & (x-3)^2 + (y-4)^2 & = (y-2)^2\\
 \ArrowBetweenLines
 & & (x-3)^2 & = (y-2)^2 -(y-4)^2\\
  & & & = \bigl((y-2)-(y-4)\bigr)\bigl((y-2) + (y-4)\bigr)\\
 \ArrowBetweenLines
 & &x^2 - 6x + 9 & = 2 (2y -6)\\
 \ArrowBetweenLines
& & x^2 - 6x - 4y + 21 &= 0
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]